# WP Custom meta box for a specific page template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom meta box using option tree framework. It is showing for every page. I want that it will show only for a specific page. How can i do that?

I have written this code to functions.php file

```
 add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_meta_boxes' );

function custom_meta_boxes() {

   $latest_work = array(
'id'          => 'latest_work',
'title'       => 'latest-work Meta Box',
'desc'        => '',
'pages'       => array( 'page' ),
'context'     => 'normal',
'priority'    => 'high',
'fields'      => array(
  array(
    'label'       => 'latest-work',
    'id'          => 'latest-work',
    'type'        => 'text',
    'desc'        => 'Tell about your latest work',
    'std'         => '',
    'rows'        => '',
    'post_type'   => '',
    'taxonomy'    => '',
    'class'       => ''
  )
)  
);
ot_register_meta_box( $latest_work );
}
```

Please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: what do you mean by specific page?

Comment: home page, blog page, about page etc

Comment: you can't detect the specific page in admin panel

Comment: why? page created from admin section . so why not detect the specific page in admin panel?

Comment: why do you need it for specific page? and not for all?

Comment: Because i want to add meta information only my home page. not for blog page. if custom meta box content on blog page then it make confuse.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45483/discussion-between-jogesh-pi-and-bir)

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_post_meta_boxes' );

function remove_post_meta_boxes() {
    // lets assume blog page has the id 23
    // let's remove the meta box from blog
    if( isset($_GET['post']) && $_GET['post'] == 23 ){
        remove_meta_box( 'latest_work', 'page', 'normal' );
    }
}
```

take a look for more information [remove_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following.

```
$post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;

    // checks for post/page ID for example i have added 7

    if ($post_id == '7'){
/.add_meta box code inside
}
```